# What are the human rights' cultural rights?

Tags: human-rights

Is there a definition for the "cultural rights" protected by the International Covenant on Economic, Social and Cultural Rights? Are they listed somewhere?

BTW, is there a complete list of all human rights protected by international <s>treatises</s> treaties (*thanks for the correction user6726!*) ?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under [Article 15(1)(a)](http://www.ohchr.org/EN/ProfessionalInterest/Pages/CESCR.aspx), "To take part in cultural life". "Cultural life" is left undefined. As far as I know, there isn't a complete list of international treaties (a treatise is something else). There is a list in a treatise (not treaty), [The Universal Declaration of Human Rights](http://www.un.org/en/universal-declaration-human-rights/), which figure in various treaties. [This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Human_rights#International_treaties) lists some of the rights claimed in various treaties.

Comment: You're right. Adding some thoughts, this Factsheet http://www.ohchr.org/Documents/Publications/FactSheet33en.pdf from the UN states cultural rights thus: "Cultural rights, including the right to participate in cultural life and to share in and benefit from scientific advancement, and protection of authors’ moral and material interests from scientific, literary or artistic production". Thanks a lot for the answer!